# Disable UI Automation for Silverlight controls (combobox, etc.)

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, memory-leaks, combobox

I've been getting memory leaks in Silverlight because of the UI automation framework as documented [here](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/sloscialo/silverlight-memory-leaks-and-automationpeers)

We implement custom control libraries (controls which inherit basic Silverlight controls and extend their functionality). e.g.

```
<local:BaseControl x:Name="DropDownControl" x:Class="xxx.xxx.Views.DropDown"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:xxx.CustomControls.Views"  
mc:Ignorable="d"

d:DesignHeight="23" d:DesignWidth="120" Background="#FF1F3B53">
<Border x:Name="bdrMain" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Transparent">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <ComboBox x:Name="ddlMainControl" Canvas.ZIndex="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

I can disable automation for the Custom Control itself by overriding the OnCreateAutomationPeer method in the class itself.

```
protected override System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
{
   return null;
}
```

However, the Combobox iteself must still respond to requests from the Automation Provider for its Automation Peer as I can still see it leaking in WinDBG. Any ideas on how to disable Automation for the Combobox in this scenario?

P.S. - I know you disable automation application wide by setting the windowless param = true but it's a mature application and I'd prefer not to change anything application wide that might add risk

Answer (score 0):

The default panel is the `VirtualisingStackPanel` which may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea what you mean? Default panel for where?